# Why is the structure of the JavaScript Object different when passed as a prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so I have a state stored in my App.js for my React app which has this structure:

```js
state = {
    A: "Some text.",
    B: {
        C: "Some extra text."
    }
}
```

And I want to print the value of `C` in a component called Header. So I passed it like this:

```js
<React.Fragment>
    <Header headerTitle= {this.state.B.C} />
</React.Fragment>
```

And in the header component, I logged it to see what it looks like:

```js
class Header extends Component {
    render = () => {
        const header = this.props
        console.log(header)
        return (
            <h2>{header}</h2>
    }
```

On the console it looked like this:

```js
{C: "Some extra text."}
```

So, my question is, why is it like this? Why can't I get the value of `C` directly?

Comment: You probably wanted: `const { headerTitle } = this.props`

Comment: A component can have many `props`. That object holds all of them for the component.

Comment: But why though? I thought it would work like normal, you know what I mean?

Comment: I see. Thanks again :)

Comment: `props` are *all* the props; that's why it's called `props`. If you were intending to destructure then see the first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not destructing the prop to get `headerTitle`.
Props is an object which contains all the property objects you pass from parent

Your code should be:

```
const header = this.props.headerTitle;
```

or you can use ES6's destructing assignment syntax, like below:

```
const { headerTitle } = this.props;
```

To clear your confusion lets say you are passing down two props to your child component:

```
<React.Fragment>
    <Header headerTitle= {this.state.B.C} headerContent= {'Blah Blah Blah'} />
</React.Fragment>
```

Now in your child component, obviously `const header = this.props` wouldn't work.
It should be:

```
const { headerTitle, headerContent } = this.props;
```

Refer the below link to understand **Destructing assignment syntax**:
[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)